# Iterate over object and input each property into a function

Tags: node.js, iteration, javascript-objects

I have this node.js object.

```
DataObj =
{ 
    ID: { data: '1' },
    IS_PRESENT: { data: '1' },
    DATA_TYPE: { data: '1' }
}
;
```

I have a function which can take each property of `DataObj` as an argument.

```
function processDataObj(DataObj_property)
{
    //blah blah
}
```

I would like to iterate over all the properties inside the object `DataObj` and put each of the property as a parameter inside function `processDataObj()`.

Something like;

```
processDataObj(ID: { data: '1' });
processDataObj(IS_PRESENT: { data: '1' });
processDataObj(DATA_TYPE: { data: '1' });
```

How can this be done iteratively in node.js code?

Comment: thoose three processDataObj examples are invalid btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
processDataObj(ID: { data: '1' });
```

Parameter is not valid. If you want to send an object like

```
processDataObj({ID: { data: '1' }});
```

Then

```
var DataObj =
{ 
    ID: { data: '1' },
    IS_PRESENT: { data: '1' },
    DATA_TYPE: { data: '1' }
};


function processDataObj(obj) {
  console.log(obj);
}


Object.keys(DataObj).forEach(function(val, index, arr) {
  var data = {};
  data[val] = DataObj[val]
  processDataObj(data);
});
OR
for (obj in DataObj) {
  var data = {};
  data[obj] = DataObj[obj];
  processDataObj(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the function with `invalid parameters` and you will get `syntax error` and I think the parameter should be like this way-

```
processDataObj({ID: { data: '1' }});
```

and if it's true then you can get it easily by this iteration.

```
var DataObj = {
    ID: {
        data: '1'
    },
    IS_PRESENT: {
        data: '1'
    },
    DATA_TYPE: {
        data: '1'
    }
};

for (var i in DataObj) {
    var newObj = {};
    newObj[i] = DataObj[i];
    processDataObj(newObj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

since you are in a nodejs environment i'd recommend trying new syntax sugar:

```
Object.keys(DataObj).forEach((key, index, object) => processDataObj(object[key]));
```

you might need to put `"use strict";` on top of your script into line 1.

this is es6 syntax. pure javascript.